# "the only other colleague" - implies how many total number of colleagues?

Tags: expressions

It is stated that a department has at least two employees. Further said that Mr F's only other colleague Mr.G earns the maximum salary".

This was part of a puzzle which could be solved if I interpret that Mr F has more than one colleague. 
Because colleague cannot mean 'himself', and the other suggests that the colleague is not singular, I am convinced that "G being the only other colleague of Mr F" means , for Mr. F,there is at least one more colleague other than Mr. G.

My question is: how to interpret the phrase "the only other colleague" ?
And is my interpretation of the phrase acceptable?

Comment: One of the employees could be a janitor. Anyway, I don't see how about word puzzles is germane to a real world question about EL&U.

Comment: The first sentence omits key information. For example, are Mr. F and Mr. G members of the department referenced? What does *colleague* mean -- could Mr. F and/or Mr. G have colleagues in other departments? As worded, if Mr. F and Mr. G are both members of the department referenced, and *colleagues* means members of the same department, then the use of "only other" implies that the department has exactly two members: Mr. F and Mr. G.

Answer (score 0):

Word puzzles are germane to English language and usage because they teach people how to think about the way in which words are used.

Anyway, that phrase implies that Mr. F has two colleagues unless there's some qualifying statement like "The only other colleague of Mr. F that ______ is Mr. G."